# Examples of use of autocomplete options on bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm trying to understand how the autocomplete structure works, but the help pages don't contain enough detail.(Yes, I also checked the [official source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html).) Could you please give some simple examples showing the intended use of the following options?

```
[-G globpat] [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix]
```

I'm sure the examples you will present will be incredibly useful to many people trying to understand the autocomplete structure.